# Operation parameters not populated

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wsdl, wcf-security

I have a WCF service with the below service\operation\data contracts.

```
namespace Enrollment
{    
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512")]
    public interface wstep
    {
        [OperationContract(Action = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/pki/2009/01/enrollment/RST/wstep", Name = "RequestSecurityToken")]
        RequestSecurityTokenResponseCollection RequestSecurityToken(string TokenType, string RequestType, BinarySecurityToken binarySecurityToken, AdditionalContext additionalContext);
    }

    [DataContract(Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2006/12/authorization")]
    public class AdditionalContext
    {
        [DataMember]
        public List<ContextItem> contextItem { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract(Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2006/12/authorization")]
    public class ContextItem
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name="Value")]
        public object Item { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot("BinarySecurityToken")]
    [DataContract(Namespace = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd", Name = "BinarySecurityToken")]
    public class BinarySecurityToken
    {
        [XmlAttribute("ValueType")]
        [DataMember(Name = "ValueType",Order=1)]        
        public string ValueType { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("EncodingType")]
        [DataMember(Name = "EncodingType", Order = 2)]
        public string EncodingType { get; set; }
    }
}
```

However, I see that the client connects to the service but the last two parameters of the Operation - BinarySecurityToken and AdditionalContext are null when I check their values in the service. I have traced the client request, and I see the values are sent by the client correctly. The below mentioned is the SOAP body.

```
<s:Body>
    <wst:RequestSecurityToken>
        <wst:TokenType>http://schemas.microsoft.com/5.0.0.0/ConfigurationManager/Enrollment/DeviceEnrollmentToken</wst:TokenType>
        <wst:RequestType>http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/Issue</wst:RequestType>
        <wsse:BinarySecurityToken ValueType="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/pki/2009/01/enrollment#PKCS10" EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd#base64binary">MIICcTCCAV0CAQAwMDEuMCwGA1UEAxMlQj=</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
        <ac:AdditionalContext xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2006/12/authorization">
            <ac:ContextItem Name="DeviceType">
                <ac:Value>MyDevice</ac:Value>
            </ac:ContextItem>
            <ac:ContextItem Name="ApplicationVersion">
                <ac:Value>18.10.6603.101</ac:Value>
            </ac:ContextItem>
        </ac:AdditionalContext>
    </wst:RequestSecurityToken>
</s:Body>
```

The first two parameters are showing up correctly. No idea what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

You can not send an `object` type instance over WCF. You need to declare the types which will be sent over service using `ServiceKnownType` attribute.

```
[DataMember(Name="Value")]
public object Item { get; set; }
```

for instance, if you know object can only be an instance of X class, then;

```
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(x))]
public interface wstep
```

Also, if you want to change the structure of the serialized xml, refer to the following [data contract serialization vs xml serialization](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/carmelh/archive/2008/10/07/contract-serialization-vs-xml-serialization.aspx)

Comment: I changed it to return type string - but that also doesn't work!

Comment: you are trying to change the structure of the xml sent; you need to change the serialization mechanism. please refer to the link I have provided.